# Bounding the ratio of two functions given their Laplace Transforms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, oc.optimization-and-control, laplace-transform

Suppose $h(i)$ is a probability density that's "nice" in some sense, and $g(i)=E[f(i,x)]=\int \mathrm{d}i\ h(i)f(i,x)$

How could I bound the following ratio $r(t)$ from above?
$$
r(t)=\frac{E[f_2(i,t)]}{E[f_1(i,t)]}
$$
where $f_1,f_2$ are solutions to the following differential equations with initial conditions $f_x(i,0)=1$. Both tend to zero as $t$ increases.
$$
\begin{cases}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f_1(i,t) =-2 f(i,t)h(i)\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} f_2(i,t) = E[f(i,t)]-2 f(i,t)h(i) \end{cases}
$$
In practice I'm finding the ratio is to be $\approx 2$ for density $g$ of the form $g(x)\propto x^k$, but I'm having trouble showing this rigorously. There's a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694070/998) to both equations in terms of Laplace Transform. I can invert Laplace Transform of one but not the other. Can I operate in Laplace domain to get bound on the ratio in the time domain?

Motivation: this would allow me to bound the loss after $t$ steps of stochastic gradient descent relative to $t$ steps of gradient descent where eigenvalue density is $h$ in a certain simplified setting.

Comment: If the LT expression is really hard to work with, you might be better off replacing some of the nonlinear functions (like the arctan one) by polynomial bounds (eg. from Taylor expansion) and then using the inverse-FT formula for $f_{1},f_{2}$ to bound their ratio.